# possible solution to php allowed memory exhausted : copy data to temporary db

Tags: php, mysql

As you can guess from the title, I am working with over 250 MBs of data and hence getting the PHP memory exhausted error.
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); is a possible solution but I dont know why I feel it is an unsafe technique. Are there any cons of using it?

My solution is to copy all the relevant data to a temporary database, do whatever I need to, and delete it.
The user might close the tab before deletion actually occurs so I would check for the existing temporary databases before every operation and if it exists, I will delete it.

Is it a good way to approach?

Thanks!

Comment: having a memory limit of 128-512MB is common these days. 250MB of data isnt much, maybe you are wasting memory? how much memory do you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In special cases, you can adjust the size of the memory:

```
$memory_berfore = ini_get('memory_limit'); // in your php.ini
// New Limit
ini_set('memory_limit','256M'); //128M, 256M, 512M, 1024M,... (X*2M)
...
your treatment 
...
// Older Limit
ini_set('memory_limit',$memory_berfore);
```